# Determine if the given file content, content-type and extension matches in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application, where I want to determine the correct file extension for an uploaded file. I think this question isn't limited to Spring Boot, or Spring in general, but more to Java. It might be the case that Spring has some utilities for determining this, but I haven't be able found a useful resource or answer for the subject. Anyway, here comes my problem.

I Spring Boot, I have a controller method, which handles uploading of files. For simplicity, call this method `uploadFile`. The signature is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadFile(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
    ) throws IOException {
        // determine the correctness of the file.
        return "";
    }
```

When the user, for example uploads a `.docx` file, but the content-type is different - excuse me for the silly example - like: text/html and the actual file is a `image/png` picture. Is there an easy way to check the file for correctness? I would like to get the right extension and mimetype for an uploaded file. The reason for this is that I want to prevent uploaded files to execute unwanted code on my server.

Is this even a security risk? If it isn't, I still need to be able to get the file extension, so any resources or helper classes are welcome!

Comment: Any user can easily modify the extension. You can also check the mime-type, which is again editable with softwares. I would recommend clearing the meta-data and mimetype of the uploaded file if security is the main problem. Do that in first place, and once that is done, you can work on determining which type of file has the user uploaded.

Comment: I know that the mimetype can be modified using software. Therefore I'm asking for any resources regarding this problem. I also know the extension can easily be changed by a user, this is knowledge that is needed prior to answering this post.  Perhaps I'm not that clear in my question.